# Weka prediction using SMO classifier in c# code

Tags: c#, weka, smo, prediction

I'm using Weka libraries via IKVM, and I've built a model with Weka explorer for the SMO. Now I want to use it for prediction on unlabelled data in the code (which I've successfully done with J48).

I load the model like this:

```
weka.classifiers.functions.SMO smo = (weka.classifiers.functions.SMO)SerializationHelper.read("C:\\Users\\lorenzov\\Desktop\\weka_files\\Modelli\\SMO_modello.model");
```

This code is for J48:

```
  weka.core.Instances test = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("C:\\Users\\lorenzov\\Desktop\\weka_files\\test.arff"));
        test.setClassIndex(5);

        // istanze da etichettare
        Instances labeled = new Instances(test);



        const int percentSplit = 66;
        int trainSize = test.numInstances() * percentSplit / 100;
        int testSize = test.numInstances() - trainSize;

        weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation eval = new weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation(test);

        eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);


        eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);

        for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++)
        {
            weka.core.Instance currentInst = test.instance(i);
            test.instance(i).classValue();
            double predictedClass = cls.classifyInstance(currentInst);
            labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(predictedClass);

        }
```

How can I do this with the SMO model?

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace your classifier line with this one below.

```html
weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.functions.SMO();
```